# Obtaining first level managers in a "reports to" recursive hierarchy

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j database with nodes USER and Relationship REPORTS_TO denoting management hierarchy in an organization. These paths can be anywhere from 0 (leaf nodes) to 7 in size. I'd like to identify the "first level managers", or those USERs who have subordinates but those subordinates have no subordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `REPORTS_TO` relationship type is only used to connect `USER` nodes, this should work for you:

```
MATCH (manager:USER)<-[:REPORTS_TO]-(a:USER)
WHERE SIZE((a)<-[:REPORTS_TO]-()) = 0
WITH manager, COUNT(a) AS peonCount, SIZE((manager)<-[:REPORTS_TO]-()) AS subordinateCount
WHERE peonCount = subordinateCount
RETURN manager
```

It makes use of a very efficient relationship degreeness check (twice), and compares the number of each manager's subordinates who are "peons" (i.e., without their own subordinates) with that manager's total number of subordinates.

An efficient degreeness check is used for a relationship expression if the expression does not specify any property values (for the end nodes or the relationship) and has one end node completely unqualified (i.e., without even a label). In this situation, neo4j does not need to actually fetch from the DB such relationships or their unqualified end nodes.